# How much should I change my high profile answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I have two high profile accepted answers in the #redis tag.

[Memcached vs. Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558465/memcached-vs-redis/11257333#11257333)

[What is Redis and what do I use it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888880/what-is-redis-and-what-do-i-use-it-for/7897243#7897243)

These both rank highly in google search results and are regularly upvoted despite their age. These two answers alone are responsible for probably most of my SO score.

They are dated and I'm not entirely happy with their format or content. I'd like to update them, but also think it would be good to completely re-write them, with a clearer summary at the top and expanding further into Redis within the answers.

However, I'm not sure how much change is appropriate. People upvoted the answers as they were and though I have updated them I've avoided making the changes drastic. It seems like a case could be made that a drastic change violates the intent of those upvotes. They are attached to the content, not to me personally, and who knows if those same up-voters would agree that my drastic re-write represents an improvement.

Are there SO guidelines for maintaining and improving high visibility answers like this? I thought I'd ask before I try to re-write these answers completely this weekend.

### Defining "Drastic"

One of the posts recently received this comment.

> what about some simple examples of use cases? and some simple examples of bad ideas to use with redis? 900 upvotes? really?

The commenter is not wrong.

I have no intention of changing the meaning, conclusion, or overall concept of the answers. My intention would be to have an expanded summary, with hopefully more readable but longer and more numerous sections beneath. Both posts don't mention new advances/features in redis and major shifts in the ecosystem, maturity, and adoption. The memcached v redis post in particular was written at a time when memcached still made some sense and had the larger install base and ecosystem. It would be good to re-write this comparison from a modern perspective so the reader has an honest understanding of the situation today, not some strange snapshot from 2012.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like your answers.

Given the edit to your question here stating "*I have no intention of changing the meaning, conclusion, or overall concept of the answers*," I don't see why it would be a problem to expand on an existing post.

When there is as much attention as is seen in the posts you highlight, expanding on them over time to make them more relevant makes a lot of sense. Removal of content is where things can get a little tricky. Seeing as how (with your clarification) that is not the intent (which it seemed at first) then there shouldn't be any reason not to go ahead with adding more information.

In a more general sense, if there is a need to drastically change answers and remove or replace large sections of content, then I would suggest writing a canonical post about the issue or writing a separate answer instead.

Comment: These are all good points, but I feel like the "mostly leave it alone" approach could provide the sizeable google audience with incomplete or at least outdated information. I'm most concerned about these users and not sure how to balance the desire to provide them accurate information with the norms of Stackoverflow and the expectation that answers are mostly static. I often arrive at SO or other exchange sites via google and am often disappointed by how outdated the answers I find are. This problem will only get worse with time.

Comment: I think that users interested in the topic would definitely follow through to a canonical post you promote in the post for a more up-to-date analysis or explanation.

Comment: There isn't really an expectation for answers to be static, but drastically overhauling them with a separate answer is perhaps over the top.

Comment: Despite my rep I guess I'm still somewhat of an SO newb. What is a "canonical post"? Something like the tag wiki or documentation posts?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was a common phrase. It is where you post both the question and the answer in order to present a high quality explanation of something on topic. This is probably my favorite canonical post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: I updated my question with my definition of drastic. Would be interested to know if you still feel "drastic" edits as defined would be too far. I appreciate the help so far.

Comment: I see, perhaps I misunderstood your intent at first. See edits.

Comment: I disagree with this a bit - I don't think that splitting off a second question/answer is the right approach here. If there's more info that you feel is relevant to improve an answer you've written, then it's appropriate to add it to the original answer - neither time nor upvotes changes that. If anything, creating another question to give a second place post more answer risks giving the appearance of trying to double-dip for votes.

Comment: @sphanley - Here? No, not given the clarifications. In the original state the implication was that the answer would have its content *replaced*. This is the scenario that represents "drastic" in my opinion, and if you need to entirely replace an answer, then it should be its own answer. If there is a different context to it, then it needs its own question. Thus, it would be more appropriate to create a canonical post in the scenario where you are replacing all of the content of your answer.

Comment: @TravisJ in the edited state, at least, it seems to me that the asker is talking about "replacing" the answer only where needed to improve clarity or depth -- the implication seems clear that this is going to still be the same answer in spirit, just reimplemented, so to speak, in a better-engineered form.

Answer (score 30):

> I have no intention of changing the meaning, conclusion, or overall concept of the answers. My intention would be to have an expanded summary, with hopefully more readable but longer and more numerous sections beneath.

That's awesome. Just do it. There is no problem with improving your content as much as you want, as long as the original meaning stays the same (and it's still a valid answer to the question).

> People upvoted the answers as they were

People got value from your post as it was when they voted on it. You working on improving the post doesn't change that one iota. Should someone seriously disagree with the improved post, they will be able to retract their upvote if they wish.

As a side note, if you ever find yourself in a situation that you have an extremely trivial, highly upvoted answer that is impossible to improve (or you just don't want to put in the work), what I have done in the past is to ask my profile to be disassociated from content I am ashamed of having gained a lot of rep for. That way the content stays in place, but it is no longer linked to your profile.

Comment: "original meaning stays the same" unless, you know, the original is dangerously wrong and obsolete and... why are you using <blink>!?!?

Answer (score -1):

If you are thinking of making "drastic" changes to an answer, but are worried that something will be lost by removing the original, I think the best course of action would be to **write or re-write as much as you like, preserving the original answer at the bottom**.

After searching for some examples (these aren't necessarily model answers, just proof that I haven't imagined seeing this tactic):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309302/best-way-to-wrap-text-around-figures-in-expl3

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125610/filling-under-plot

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/82307/package-revision-after-probation

Answer (score -10):

If your contribution was so valued, rather than change the original post, you might consider creating a website article (or series of articles) about it. Adding a link to your site would assist people who were really interested in the details.

I note that this has already been done, with links to your stack overflow post, e.g. http://www.engineersbloc.com/collection/277/ (And I also note that you've already accepted one of the above answers so maybe it's a bit of a moot point.)